# Query by Example Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-data, query-by-example

I have domain object Person with date fields:

```
public class Person {
@Id
private Long id;
private Date date
```

Build example like this:

```
Person person = new Person();
person.setSomeOtherFields("some fields");
Example<Person> example = Example.of(person);
```

How i can create example query with date range (search entity contains date greater or equal from some date and less or equal some another date)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Data JPA query-by-example technique uses `Example`s and `ExampleMatcher`s to convert entity instances into the underlying query. The [current official documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example.introduction) clarifies that only exact matching is available for non-string attributes. Since your requirement involves a `java.util.Date` field, you can only have exact matching with the query-by-example technique.

You could write your own `ExampleMatcher` that returns query clauses according to your needs.